# Find textblock name using string value

Tags: vb.net, textblock

My title might be weird. I don't know how to say this. Here are the point. I have an arraylist which hold some dynamic data count. It can be 10, 20 or 30 data or whatever data exist in database. At my page, I have 42 textblock in 2 column. Which mean I have a column of "my number" and a column of "my name". 42 textblock is static. But the arraylist data is dynamic. How to loop throught the arraylist and fill the textblock by the total data in arraylist? I just do some code, but I can't think the logic.

```
Private Sub FillOthers()
        Dim name1, name2 As TextBlock
        Try
            For i = 1 To (arrOthers.Count)
                name1 = "tbothers_no" & i
                name2 = "tbothers_name" & i
                name1.Text = arrOthers.Item(i).dirno
                name2.Text = arrOthers.Item(i).dirname
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            strErrMsg = "Error at fill others textblock. " & vbCrLf & ex.Message
            Application.LogEvents(strErrMsg, EventLogEntryType.Error)
        End Try
End Sub
```

See the name1 and name2. I want the data is fill in the textblock by the counting of loop. Now I got error the string value can't be convert to textblock. Any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want [FrameworkElement::FindName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname.aspx). Something like this should work:

```
Dim name1, name2 As TextBlock
For i = 1 to arrOthers.Count
    name1 = TryCast(FindName("tbothers_no" & i), TextBlock)
    If name1 IsNot Nothing Then name1.Text = arrOthers.Item(i).dirno

    name2 = TryCast(FindName("tbothers_name" & i), TextBlock)
    If name2 IsNot Nothing Then name2.Text = arrOthers.Item(i).dirname
Next
```

Comment: Hi joe, just got this from internet. See my answer. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

My finding, testing and it's works!

```
   Dim tb1(9) As TextBlock
   Dim tb2(9) As TextBlock

   tb1(0) = tbothers_dir1
   tb1(1) = tbothers_dir2
   tb1(2) = tbothers_dir3
   tb1(3) = tbothers_dir4
   tb1(4) = tbothers_dir5
   tb1(5) = tbothers_dir6
   tb1(6) = tbothers_dir7
   tb1(7) = tbothers_dir8
   tb1(8) = tbothers_dir9
   tb1(9) = tbothers_dir10

   tb2(0) = tbothers_name1
   tb2(1) = tbothers_name2
   tb2(2) = tbothers_name3
   tb2(3) = tbothers_name4
   tb2(4) = tbothers_name5
   tb2(5) = tbothers_name6
   tb2(6) = tbothers_name7
   tb2(7) = tbothers_name8
   tb2(8) = tbothers_name9
   tb2(9) = tbothers_name10

   For i = 0 To (arrOthers.Count - 1)
       tb1(i).Text = arrOthers.Item(i).strdirno
       tb2(i).Text = arrOthers.Item(i).strdirname
   Next
```